# How to get the selected checkbox item in code behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, checkbox, observablecollection, multi-select

I am attempting to populate an ObservableCollection with the currently selected items in a MultiSelectList. The method of selection involves a checkbox control, and I am unsure of how to get the selected items to populate the ObservableCollection. I have referenced two methods which perform a single selection of the MultiSelectList as well as a 'select all' option of the MultiSelectList.

To note, networkSelectList is an ObservableCollection in a custom Settings class.

MainPage.xaml

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList x:Name="connectionTypeMultiSelectList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tap="connectionTypeMultiSelectList_Tap">
    <toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="12,0,0,0">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="35" Height="35" Margin="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center"  Margin="10"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>                            
</toolkit:MultiselectList>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
    /// method to Select All and UnSelect All checkboxes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selected"></param>
    /// <param name="predicate"></param>
    private void SetCheckBoxesSelected(bool selected, Predicate<ConnectionItem> predicate)
    {
        if (networkTypeList == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (predicate == null)
        {
            predicate = (networkInfo) => true;
        }


        ItemContainerGenerator itemContainerGenerator = this.connectionTypeMultiSelectList.ItemContainerGenerator;


        foreach (ConnectionItem networkInfo in networkTypeList)
        {
            if (networkInfo != null && predicate(networkInfo))
            {
                DependencyObject visualItem = itemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(networkInfo);
                MultiselectItem multiselectItem = visualItem as MultiselectItem;
                if (multiselectItem != null)
                {
                    multiselectItem.IsSelected = selected;

                    //add selected item to networkSelectionChecked  ??
                    //Settings.networkSelectionChecked.Value.Add(multiselectItem.Name.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// triggered on tap of any item in connectionTypeMultiSelectList
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void connectionTypeMultiSelectList_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject tappedElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        MultiselectItem tappedItem = this.FindParentOfType<MultiselectItem>(tappedElement);
        ConnectionItem selectedItem = null;
        if (tappedItem != null)
        {
            // DataContext contains reference to data item
            selectedItem = tappedItem.DataContext as ConnectionItem;
        }


        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.Name + "Tapped");

            //add selected item to networkSelectionChecked  ??
            //Settings.networkSelectionChecked.Value.Add(multiselectItem.Name.ToString());

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// method to find out the element in VisualTree
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="element"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private T FindParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        T result = null;
        DependencyObject currentElement = element;
        while (currentElement != null)
        {
            result = currentElement as T;
            if (result != null)
            {
                break;
            }
            currentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentElement);
        }
        return result;
    }

    void unselectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetCheckBoxesSelected(false, null);
        this.connectionTypeMultiSelectList.IsSelectionEnabled = false;
    }

    void selectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetCheckBoxesSelected(true, null);
    }
```

So basically I am trying to add each item that is selected to an ObservableCollection. I would like to accomplish this so that I will be able to create secondary tiles and update them by passing a querystring representing the selected checkboxes. How might I accomplish correctly adding the selected checkbox items to an ObservableCollection? Also in a similiar sense, how would I detect when an item is unselected and remove that item from the ObservableCollection? Additionally, is there a correct way to persist the selected items in the MultiSelectList so that this may be saved for future application launched or activations?

Comment: What you can do is add a boolean to your class ConnectionItem and toggle it via checkbox of multiselect in this way for the next app launch you will know which all are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected items from the SelectedItems property.

```
var selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<ConnectionItem>(connectionTypeMultiSelectList.SelectedItems.Count);
foreach (var item in TextItemsList.SelectedItems)
{
    var connectionItem = item as ConnectionItem;
    if (connectionItem == null) continue;
    selectedItems.Add(connectionItem );
}
```

The SelectionChanged event will let you know when an item is (un)selected.

```
void MultiSelectListSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        // add to collection
    }
    foreach(var item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        // remove from collection
    }
}
```